# Объясните использование websocket'ов

Tags: алгоритм, веб-программирование, laravel, websocket

Разрабатываю сайт на Laravel, необходимо использовать вебсокеты для одного из блока, в нем изменяется два поля, изменения происходят каждые пару секунд, т.е. эти изменения производят сами пользователи, и нужно чтоб изменения видели все каждые пару секунд.

Но... я не знаю с чего начать использование websocket'ов. С чего начать?

Знаю что в laravel websocoket'ы из коробки идут, но как их использовать то? Как начать?:))

Для чего нужны сторонние сервисы, типа Redis? С коробки без них не обойтись?

Comment: Не зная ничего о Laravel ввёл в поисковике “Laravel websocket” получил множество ссылок, первая из них - https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/broadcasting. Начать нужно с этого.

Comment: Ну блин.. читал я доки и не раз, но мне все равно не понятно  с чего начинать. Для чего использовать сторонние сервисы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тебе нужно сперва разобраться с концепцией работы библиотеки [soket.io](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/), благо примеры и документация там адекватные, так вот как только ты разберешься зачем нужен emit, broadcast ты поймешь, что тебе нужно где-то хранить что, от кого, кому пришло и что куда перенаправлять, тут тебе поможет Redis или pusher. Они будет хранить данные и адреса клиентов (имена соединений). Можно было бы и без них обойтись, но для этого тебе бы пришлось писать код с массивами объектов, поиском и так далее, что при больших объемах наверняка будет не оптимально.

Answer (score 1):

> Вебсокет (если и клиент и сервер оба поддерживают). Вебсокет это единственная технология транспортного уровня (is the only transport) которая устанавливает по-настоящему устойчивое [дуплексное](http://www.mir-koda.ru/full_leson_cpp.php?id=26) (two-way) соединение между клиентом и сервером. Тем не менее, Вебсокет также  предъявляет серьезные ограничения; он полностью поддерживается только в последних версиях Internet Explorer, Chome и Firefox, и только частично реализован в остальных браузерах как Opera и Safari.

(с) [msdn](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr#html-5-transports)

---

Развёрнутая информация о поддержке данной технологии доступна в [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets)

---

И может быть ютуб поможет? [Насчитал](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B) три видео на русском различной длины, предлагаю посмотреть версию [Арсена](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ROwCDBIP6fU) - 20 минут. Или от [Geekbrains](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4cMGycUOjas) - два часа рассказывают.

Answer (score 1):

Евгений, я наткнулся на исчерпывающее описание веб-технологий в принципе. В частности там идет об интересующей Вас теме. Также оставляю это здесь для всяк сюда входящего: [ссылка](https://www.programmableweb.com/news/what-websockets-push-styled-api-and-how-does-it-work/analysis/2017/04/20)

Этот цикл статей просто потрясающий!